# MC34063ADR overheats and burns

Tags: voltage-regulator, negative-voltage, buck-boost

I am trying to get -13.5V from mc34063.

On the first design, I used 8DIP package MDR34063AP and no problem getting -13.5V.

On the second design changed the package to 8-soic and used S1B-13F (100V 1A diode), which are replacements with same characteristics.

However, after 2 seconds IC starts to consume more and more current gets hot and burns.

When I increased the R22=1R resistor to 2.5R, it doesn't overheat but I can't get -13.5V anymore. It stays around -9V.

Any comment or help would be really useful,

Thank you for your time.

Design 1
[image]

Design 2
 [image]

Comment: On second design, D7 is elsewhere. Not missing.

Comment: S1B-13F, 1N400x are inappropriate for SMPS designs- too long recovery time even for a pig of a chip like 34063- and not even specified. Use a Schottky diode like the datasheet shows. Is the inductor the same in both cases?

Comment: have a close look at the chip. there may have been a mixup with part numbers

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thank you so much Spehro, switching to Schottky solved the issue! Thank you for your help, sending you all the good karma!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1B-13F, 1N400x are inappropriate for SMPS designs- too long recovery time even for a pig of a chip like 34063- and not even specified so the specs can be met yet the diodes can be very different.

Use a Schottky diode like the datasheet shows. An ultra fast diode such as UF4004 can also be used.

Inductor saturation is another thing to look for if that part changed.